RC or RL high pass audio filter?
Some bass guitars from the 60s, namely Gibson and Guild, used RL, LC, or RLC high pass filters to reduce bass frequencies if desired.  The control for these switches was commonly referred to as the "suck" switch.  Both manufacturers used coils for inductors.
So, my new questions are:
Why would Gibson and Guild use more expensive, and potentially noisier, L type filters?  Everything else they did, they did as cheaply as possible.  Is there an audible advantage to using L type filters instead of RC filters?

Please let me know if you require more specifics.
I understand how RC and RL high bypass filters work.
What I want to know is, which one is better for audio signals, and why?
Thank you!

You probably need to define "better".

inductive filters are rarely used because:

they are physically bigger, particularly for filters at low frequencies, which you need for audio
coils are more expensive
coils are susceptible to external interference (they like to be the secondary of an accidental transformer)

It is also possible to simulate an inductor with opamps and capacitors, using a gyrator circuit. This is sometimes used in place of inductors.
However, passive filters using inductors were once commonplace, and there are modern designs which seek to emulate them. There are those that believe that such devices have a special sound signature and pay large sums for such products.
UPDATING THIS ANSWER BASED ON UPDATED QUESTION
You've update the question to discuss guitar electronics, specifically from a time before active electronics in guitars was generally not possible because of size. It looks like the 4th position of the switch connects a series LC circuit from the end of one pickup to ground. Because a series LC has minimal impedance at resonance (set by the resistance of the inductor) this will have the effect of loading the pickup at that frequency, reducing its output. Hence the name "suck" - it is sucking the mid-range from the signal.
The reason for using an inductor is simple - there is no other way to make a series resonant circuit with passive circuitry. You need both L and C elements, and without active electronics, an inductor is the only way.
I'm curious about the way the inductor is drawn - it suggests some sort of special winding, but what exactly that is is not clear.

Your updated question invalidates my answer below:
I can't say which one is better because of the lack of what "better" means for you, but I can mention a disadvantage of an LR filter:
Both can eliminate DC but the "cost of DC removal" in RL may be higher: If the source signal has a DC offset then the RL filter may draw more current because it doesn't block the DC path so the dissipation will be higher. To reduce the dissipation the series resistor (R) can be increased but this will result in increasing the inductance of L i.e. quite possibly a bigger inductance.

UPDATE AFTER QUESTION UPDATE
When the switch is at the 4th position the front pickup will be active, and will be loaded by the LC tank formed by the choke (70-442) and the 470n capacitor to the bottom (70-904).
The response will be a high-Q (well, high enough) notch filter:

NOTE: The plot above does not represent the actual response of the pickup.
The reason why they used an LC tank should be its simplicity. With a series LC (with relatively high L therefore large in size) its possible to get the desired midrange notch. Otherwise, multiple RC networks (e.g. twin-T) would be needed.

In the context of audio, DC removal is not what filters are about. That is done with coupling caps between stages, never with inductors - it just doesn't make sense. Audio filters (equalisers) are all about cutting or boosting selected frequencies, perhaps to remove pops or unwanted LF information, to improve clarity of voices, or for aesthetic reasons. (Strictly speaking a DC block is a filter, I know, but that is not typically how the term is used in audio.)
